# What is the term to define a single point in a polychoron?

Tags: polygons

I'm looking for any correct term used to define a point in 4 dimensional space.  IE: What does a polychoron compose?

Comment: What about "point"?

Comment: [Vertices, edges, faces, cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-polytope). I guess in general (a vague recollection from a course where simplical complexes were studied) the top dimensional parts would be cells, and the lower dimensional parts various $k$-faces for varying $k$. This recollection is probably not entirely accurate :-)